# Method of object failed, missing formula

Tags: excel, vb6

ive made a code in vb6 that opens an existing excel file and compute values inside the sheet.

Problem ive encountered:
"MDURATION" formula is missing on the "opened" excel; however, i checked that stand-alone ms excel actually has that formula, so i don't know how come when an excel file is opened through vb code (which is already in .exe form), it cannot identify that function. i encounter this error on 2 PCs, although there's no problem in 3 PCs that ive tested it with.

familiar Solution i did:
I added this just right before the code where i enter formulas:

```
AddIns("Analysis ToolPak").Installed = False
AddIns("Analysis ToolPak").Installed = True
```

and it seems to work just fine on my other procedures, however on this certain procedure, it seems like this has no effect.

In addition, ive encounted a run time error 1004: Method of Object Failed on this part:

```
Range("I" & iCtrRow & "").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00000"
```

and im not sure what causes the error.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Er, this is tagged VB6 but looks like a VBA question.

Comment: Maybe try stepping through the code slowly to see if there is a timing problem with the `.Installed` method. On your second question, check the value of `iCtrRow` -- is is valid?

Comment: i can only debug this in my pc, and there seems to be no problem with the timing of .Installed. Probably there is a timing problem in that part on the pc where i run the .exe file (since i cannot debug it there)

Answer (score 1):

> In addition, ive encounted a run time error 1004: Method of Object Failed on this part:

If it is vb6 then you need to specify the complete reference. For example.

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLWB As Object, oXLSht As Object
    Dim iCtrRow As Long

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLWB = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xls")

    '~~> Change (1) to the relevant sheet
    Set oXLSht = oXLWB.Worksheets(1)

    iCtrRow = 1

    '~~> iCtrRow
    oXLSht.Range("I" & iCtrRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00000"
End Sub
```

If you are doing it in VBA, it will be like this

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim oXLWB As Workbook, oXLSht As Worksheet
    Dim iCtrRow As Long

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xls")

    '~~> Change (1) to the relevant sheet
    Set oXLSht = oXLWB.Worksheets(1)

    iCtrRow = 1

    '~~> iCtrRow
    oXLSht.Range("I" & iCtrRow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00000"
End Sub
```

Regarding the Analysis Toolpak, can you show the exact vb6 code on how you are activating it and using the "MDURATION" formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i guess i just have to include "." and use
".Range" instead of "Range"

you're right, there probably is a timing problem on the other pc, so i placed a delay in between:

AddIns("Analysis ToolPak").Installed = False
Call procdelay
AddIns("Analysis ToolPak").Installed = True

and it worked. Problem solved, thanks a lot!!